# Display maximum frequency point of each bin in ggplot2 stat_binhex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set in which a coordinate can be repeated several times.
I want to make a hexbinplot displaying the maximum number of times a coordinate is repeated within that bin. I am using R and I would prefer to make it with ggplot so the graph is consistent with other graphs in the same report.

Minimum working example (the bins display the count not the max):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
set.seed(41)
dat<-data.table(x=sample(seq(-10,10,1),1000,replace=TRUE),
           y=sample(seq(-10,10,1),1000,replace=TRUE))
dat[,.N,by=c("x","y")][,max(N)]
# No bin should be over 9

p1 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y))+stat_binhex(bins=10)
p1
```

I believe the approach should be related to this question:
[calculating percentages for bins in ggplot2 stat_binhex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950753/calculating-percentages-for-bins-in-ggplot2-stat-binhex) but I am not sure how to adapt it to my case. 
Also, I am concerned about this issue [ggplot2: ..count.. not working with stat_bin_hex anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487475/ggplot2-count-not-working-with-stat-bin-hex-anymore#comment62476216_37487475) as it can make my objective harder than what I initially thought.

Is it possible to make the bins display the maximum number of times a point is repeated?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the maximum number of times a coordinate is repeated"? I am struggling to understand the distinction between the count and the "number of times a coordinate is repeated" and have no idea what to do with "maximum" in this context.

Comment: Let's say points (0,0) and (0,1) are in the same bin and that they are the only points in that bin. The (0,0) appears 5 times and the (0,1) 3 times. In that case, the graph would display 8 because the function it uses is the count (5+3). What I would like to use is the max function and therefore display 5 (max(5,3)).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JonNagra. I had guessed at that and posted something just as you replied. I now see *what* you are trying to do, but I am really struggling with the *why* -- a use case where this is the appropriate behavior may help to elucidate a different solution (I struggle to understand how only showing the max helps display your data when it loses so much information, and hides that info from the viewer). Alternatively, below I posted an option to display all of the coordinates separately.

Comment: I think I took a wrong approach. Your post answers my question and it is really close to what I need.
About my motives, I was looking for a graph built out of hexagons because my real data has circular coordinates and the hexagons are more pleasant than the squares in those situations. Also, I wanted different resolution levels of the graphs (this is performed quite easily with the bins variable). The count was not a proper metric for me because I am measuring depth and what I really want to show is if certain level has been reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, after playing with the data a bit more, I now understand. Each bin in the plot represents multiple points, e.g., (9,9);(9,10)(10,9);(10,10) are all in a single bin in the plot. I must caution that this is the *expected* behavior. It is unclear to me why you do not want to do it this way. Instead, you seem to want to display the values of just one of those points (e.g. 9,9).

I don't think you will be able to do this directly in a call to `geom_hex` or `stat_hexbin`, as those functions are trying to faithfully represent all of the data. In fact, they are not necessarily expecting discrete coordinates like you have at all -- they work equally well on continuous data.

For your purpose, if you want finer control, you may want to instead use `geom_tile` and count the values yourself, eg. (using `dplyr` and `magrittr`):

```
countedData <-
  dat %$%
  table(x,y) %>%
  as.data.frame()

ggplot(countedData
       , aes(x = x
             , y = y
             , fill = Freq)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

and you might play with the representation a bit from there, but it would at least display each of the separate coordinates more faithfully.

Alternatively, you could filter your raw data to only include the points that *are* the maximum within a bin. That would require you to match the binning, but could at least be an option.

For completeness, here is how to adapt the `stat_summary_hex` solution that @Jon Nagra (OP) [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284615/plotting-a-hex-bin-in-r-and-ggplot2-using-a-continuous-z-fill-variable). Note that there are a few additional steps, so I don't think that this is quite a duplicate. Specifically, the table step above is required to generate something that can be used as a `z` for the summaries, and then you need to convert x and y back from factors to the original scale.

```
ggplot(countedData
       , aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(x))
             , y = as.numeric(as.character(y))
             , z = Freq)) +
  stat_summary_hex(fun = max, bins = 10
                   , col = "white")
```

[image]

Of note, I still think that the `geom_tile` may be more useful, even it is not quite as flashy.

Comment: I was looking at the hexbin library and found this post  that does exactly what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284615/plotting-a-hex-bin-in-r-and-ggplot2-using-a-continuous-z-fill-variable  
I can group the variables by x and y and use max instead of sum. I do not know if I should mark my question as a duplicate.

Comment: I just updated the answer to incorporate the solution you linked. I don't think this question is quite a duplicate, as it is starting from a different data format.

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure how to proceed in this case.